# Objective C - How do I use initWithCoder method?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nscoder

I have the following method for my class which intends to load a nib file and instantiate the object:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)aDecoder 
{
    if(self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
        // Do something
    }
    return self;
}
```

How does one instantiate an object of this class?
What is this `NSCoder`? How can I create it?

```
    MyClass *class = [[MyClass alloc] initWithCoder:aCoder];
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You also need to define the following method as follows:

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)enCoder {
    [super encodeWithCoder:enCoder];

    [enCoder encodeObject:instanceVariable forKey:INSTANCEVARIABLE_KEY];

    // Similarly for the other instance variables.
    ....
}
```

And in the initWithCoder method initialize as follows:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {

   if(self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
       self.instanceVariable = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:INSTANCEVARIABLE_KEY];

       // similarly for other instance variables
       ....
   }

   return self;
}
```

You can initialize the object standard way i.e

```
CustomObject *customObject = [[CustomObject alloc] init];
```

Comment: my main question is: "so based on this init method how do u instantiate an object of this class?"

Comment: These methods need to be defined if you are using the object for serializing and deserializing. You can initialize the object using normal init method

Comment: But... how do you invoke the initWithCoder method?

Comment: I think you are referring to  [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:<#(NSData *)#>]. Check the class methods of NSKeyedUnarchiver for reading data

Comment: @Ev You don't call initWithCoder, this method gets called as the result of loading a view from nib or storyboard.

Answer (score 18):

The `NSCoder` class is used to archive/unarchive (marshal/unmarshal, serialize/deserialize) of objects.

This is a method to write objects on streams (like files, sockets) and being able to retrieve them later or in a different place.

I would suggest you to read http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html