# how to load xib files in mainView controllers in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib, custom-view

I am very new for iOS and in my app I am loading `UIView` xib file in my mainView controller and here in this xib file i have inserted one `UITextField` but when i insert text in that text it's not applying please help me.

### mainViewController:-

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
    FirstView * test1;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize rightView;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    test1 = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FirstView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    test1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, rightView.frame.size.width, rightView.frame.size.height);

    test1.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    [rightView addSubview:test1];
}
```

UIview xib class:-
=-------

```
#import "FirstView.h"

@implementation FirstView
@synthesize textview;

-(instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{

    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {

        [self loadingView];
    }
    return self;
}

-(instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{

    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {

        [self loadingView];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)loadingView{

    textview.text = @"You are required to call in advance to schedule transportation. Time frame requirements are 48 hours for Anthem and 72 hours for MHS.\n\nYou will always need the Medicaid and Social Security number of the member who has an appointment.\n\nAll eligible members can schedule appointments up to 45 days in advance. For example, if you have existing appointments within the next 6 weeks from the current calendar date, you can schedule transportation to those appointments today.\n\nThere is only 1 adult allowed per trip. Any additional riders will need to be verified “medically necessary” by the facility representative. If a child has an appointment both parents are allowed to ride along.\n\nYou will ALWAYS need the physical address of the facility that you are going to AND the name of the doctor you will be seeing.\n\nThere is only one pick-up and one drop-off per scheduled trip.";
}

@end
```

Comment: what the problem u faced bro

Comment: bro i am loading one UIview xib files in my mainview controller that's ok it's loading fine

Comment: what is your right view , it is a view or else

Comment: and in my xid file i inserted textview with some text but text data not loading bro

Comment: yes it's also Uiview i have draged in my mainView controller and loading xib file on that rightview bro

Comment: Try to implement - (void)awakeFromNib and call -(void)loadingView there…

Comment: no , I cant understand

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B05NQoG9RAmwa0had3lzNDZpTzQ/view?usp=sharing please see this bro it's just small litttle bit problem

Comment: hi can u see this brother?

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/89025146/FirstView.m check this ;)

Comment: now loading but what is problem if i calling this from initWithCoder and initWithFrame i have big dought about it

Comment: initWithFrame - this method will be called if you create view programmatically by using this method.
initWithCoder - you can check logic here http://stackoverflow.com/a/3943838/2185873

Comment: u mean if u want to create anything through programatically hen we have to use that methods right?

Comment: Yeap. But if you are using XIB/Storyboard for initialization - awakeFromNib will be called.

Comment: Are you using xib or storyboard?In case If you use Xib,delete the storyboard and xib should be rootViewController.

Comment: First  you have to be cool and asks clearly. Everyone is ready to help you now.

Answer (score 1):

Hi can you please tell me how you created that view controller and I'm not getting you calling `UIView` xib .
What you were needed to do is create a class with xib and then put `UITextView` on that and implement the delegates methods of text view to perform whatever action on entering the text .

Comment: can i send my sample xcode file please solve my problem please